# owl carousel não funciona

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, owl-carousel

olá amigos gostaria de uma  ajuda por favor.

tÔ tentando fazer um carousel no meu site e não to conseguindo de jeito nenhum.
não sei se é algum problema no link , ou nas clases,pois do jeito que peguei no site eu inserir no codigo.  só sei que , ao inserir o html as imagens ficam todas gigante.
e ao linkar o arquivo css do carousel na pagina ,as imagens somen e a tela fica toda branca
eis aqui como ta ficando  quando insiro o html.
o que  que eu tÔ fazendo de errado ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
 
      navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem:true
 
      // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
      // items : 1, 
      // itemsDesktop : false,
      // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
      // itemsTablet: false,
      // itemsMobile : false
 
  });
 
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel();
 
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .item img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <title>carousel</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
 <!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
 
<!-- Default Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.css">
 
<!--  jQuery 1.7+  -->
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 
<!-- Include js plugin -->
<script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>oi</h1>
 <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
 
  <div class="item"><img src="img/01.jpg" alt="The Last of us"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img/02.jpg"" alt="GTA V"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img/03.jpg"" alt="Mirror Edge"></div>
 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Cara tinha alguns detalhe que eu mudei e aqui está funcionando, primeiro que tem umas aspas `"` sobrando no sue código, depois que essa versão do jQuery é bem antiga.

Além disso, vc tem só 3 imagens, que é justamente o padrão minimo de itens por slide, o que quero dizer é que **o carrossel só ativa quando tem no minimo 4 itens ou mais** por padrão na configuração por exemplo colocando `items: 2` ou `items: 1` para exibir apenas 1 item por slide. Lei mais sobre as configuraçõs aqui https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

Veja funcionando depois que eu fiz os ajustes.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="pt-br">

  <head>
      <title>carousel</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
      <!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->

      <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

      <style>
          #owl-demo .item img {
              display: block;
              width: 100%;
              height: auto;
          }
      </style>
  </head>

  <body>
      <h1>oi</h1>
      <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
          <div class="item"><img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">1</div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">2</div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">3</div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">4</div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">5</div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">6</div>
      </div>

      <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {

              $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

                  navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
                  slideSpeed: 300,
                  paginationSpeed: 400,
                  singleItem: true,
                  items: 5
              });
          });
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#owl-example").owlCarousel();
          });
      </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Valeu @hugocsl eu fiz aqui só mudei o link, em vez de linkar pelo CDN eu baixei os arquivos e linkei direto.apareceu tudo certinho só não conseguir fazer ele ir passando as img sozinho.

Comment: @Danilorodrigues entra no link da documentação que postei e procura por autoplay, não se se ele eh true por padrão, se não for vc tem que por junto das demais configurações etc

Comment: consegui graças a você obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Só não tô conseguindo  tirar as bolinhas, que é a paginação.   No código tá navigation : True,      eu mudo pra false e não funciona.                                                Qual deve ser o problema?

Comment: @Danilorodrigues acho que vc escreveu errado para tirar a navegação coloca `nav: false` e se quiser tirar as bolinhas coloca `dots: false`. Depois se vc achar que resolveu o problema da questão lembre-se de marca-la como aceita :) `✔`